# Using RSelenium to navigate to a frame with the name method

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to scrape weather data (RAWS data to be specific) from this WRCC webpage: https://wrcc.dri.edu/cgi-bin/rawMAIN.pl?caucgr

I was able to successfully select the left frame, named List, and then click on the Daily Summary Time Series link. However, my code fails when I try to use the right frame, named Graph, with the same methodology and I'm scratching my head as to why. The error message states that the element does not exist, but as I have indicated in the first screenshot, the right frame is indeed named **Graph**.

[image: Graph Frame]

I have provided my full R code below along with a screenshot of the error message [image: Frame Selection Error]

```
# Set up RSelenium -------------------------------------------------------
## load packages ----
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
library(netstat)
library(here)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

## Open a chrome browser session with RSelenium ----
rs_driver_object <-rsDriver(
  browser = 'chrome',
  chromever ='108.0.5359.71',
  port = free_port(),
  extraCapabilities = eCaps
)

remDr <- rs_driver_object$client

#Navigate to RAWS website
remDr$navigate("https://wrcc.dri.edu/cgi-bin/rawMAIN.pl?caucgr")

#Switch to Left Frame named "List"
ListFrame <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", value = "List")
remDr$switchToFrame(ListFrame)

#Select Daily Summary Time Series Link
Link1 <- remDr$findElement(using = "link text", value = "Daily Summary Time Series")
Link1$clickElement()

#Switch to Right Frame named "Graph"
GraphFrame <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", value = "Graph")
remDr$switchToFrame(GraphFrame)
```

[image: Error Message indicating that element does not exist]type here

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem thanks to a colleague: I just needed to add `remDr$switchToFrame(NA)` prior to this code block: `GraphFrame <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", value = "Graph") remDr$switchToFrame(GraphFrame)`

Answer (score 0):

You can actually gather info from the site without RSelenium. Look into `httr2`. Here I gathered info from the daily summar

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr2)

"https://wrcc.dri.edu/cgi-bin/wea_daysum2.pl" %>% 
  request() %>% 
  req_body_form(
    stn = "UCGR", 
    mon = 12, 
    day = 20, 
    yea = 22, 
    unit = "E", 
    typ = "reg"
  ) %>% 
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_html() %>% 
  html_table() 

# A tibble: 45 × 24
   X1      X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9    X10   X11   X12   X13   X14   X15   X16   X17  
   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 Hour    Total ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    Air   ""    Soil  ""    Rela… ""    ""    ""    ""    ""   
 2 of Day  Solar ""    "Win… "Win… "Win… ""    Temp… ""    Temp… ""    Humi… ""    "Dew" "Wet" ""    "Bar…
 3 Ending… Rad.  ""    "Ave… "V. … "Max… ""    Mean  ""    Mean  ""    Mean  ""    "Poi… "Bul… ""    "Pre…
 4 L.S.T.  ° ly. ""    "mph" "Deg" "mph" ""    Deg.… ""    Deg.… ""    Perc… ""    "Deg… "Deg… ""    "in.…
 5 1 am    0.0   ""    "3.6" "288" "4.7" ""    36.1  ""    42.2  ""    29    ""    "7"   "27"  ""    "25.…
 6 2 am    0.0   ""    "3.7" "284" "4.9" ""    35.3  ""    41.8  ""    32    ""    "8"   "26"  ""    "25.…
 7 3 am    0.0   ""    "3.6" "287" "5.1" ""    36.2  ""    41.4  ""    32    ""    "9"   "27"  ""    "25.…
 8 4 am    0.0   ""    "2.3" "288" "4.3" ""    37.7  ""    41.0  ""    30    ""    "9"   "28"  ""    "25.…
 9 5 am    0.0   ""    "1.9" "284" "3.8" ""    37.1  ""    40.7  ""    31    ""    "9"   "28"  ""    "25.…
10 6 am    0.0   ""    "3.2" "286" "5.8" ""    37.1  ""    40.4  ""    30    ""    "8"   "28"  ""    "25.…
# … with 35 more rows, and 7 more variables: X18 <chr>, X19 <chr>, X20 <chr>, X21 <chr>, X22 <chr>,
#   X23 <chr>, X24 <chr>
```

Comment: Thanks Tom; I appreciate your explanation and I see the value on using rvest and httr2. However, I need to use RSelenium because I need to scrape data specifically from the webpage I indicated so that I can filter the data based on the drop-down menus. Some of the drop-down variables are available in your code, but others are not such as:

*Select the Data Summarization requirements
*Apply Physical limits QC to data:
*Represent Missing data as -9999
*Include # of valid observations for each element